# css div align why works only inline

Tags: css

I wonder why align doesn't work when used in external style sheet but works fine in inline (correct me if I'm wrong)
and also I can't use both align and external styilng by using an id for div

http://www.jsfiddle.net/pahnin/rdgbq/5/

Comment: Because of priority of CSS selectors, but that is easy to "fix".. if you provide some code..

Comment: @pahnin, your example works as expected.. if you remove the align attribute the text will remain centered from the css rule..

Comment: @pahnin what @Gaby says. Works as designed. If you want to center the logo, use `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` (Jsfiddle here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/NWgFn/) or make `#logo` an inline element

Comment: i'm not talking abt the text I'm talking abt the div itself when I give inline attribut it was ignored by outline styling but when i remove the id attr i can have the centering , also i can't use align in externel style sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline styles have a higher priority that either embedded or external styles (this is a core principle of *cascading* style sheets).  I sounds highly likely that you have an align that is inadvertently affecting your element, which is overwritten when you use inline styles.

** **edit** **

I see what you mean now - your align is actually an HTML attribute, not CSS - and `align=center` doesn't work with block elements the same way you would expect it to with tables.

Fortunately it's easy to fix as you have set widths for the logo and footer.  Simply set equal left and right margins of 45% to your logo element (and remove the align=center).

```
#logo {
    margin: 0 45%;
}
```

Comment: see the link i added there using id and external styling is disabling inline align

Comment: Here's the solution if you're attempting to centre the logo on the page.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. CSS rules work the same way, whether they are defined in external style sheets or in inline CSS.

There are some mistakes one can make when embedding external style sheets, for example using a `title` attribute in the `link` tag, or using the wrong `media` attribute.

Maybe one of these things causes your external style sheet not to work. In that case, show the code you are using to embed it.

Comment: i think the OP refers to inline as in the `style` attribute, which takes priority over all other css rules..

Comment: @Gaby I agree, but that doesn't explain why it wouldn't work in an external style sheet, does it?

Comment: yes you are right.. i got confused and thought he was using both .. but he does not say this .. wrong assumption.